# Issue with code after upgrade to xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, xcode7

I have this piece of code that was working fine with xcode6 and after upgrading to xcode7 I am getting the following error

```
var levels:[(
                level: Int,
                activeButtons: [UIButton],
                numberOfButtons: Int,
                timer: [Int],
                blinks: [Int],
                score: [Int],
                subIndex: Int,
                image: String,
                bunce : Int,
                speed: Double

    )] = []
levels.append(level:1, activeButtons:[], numberOfButtons:2, timer:[0,10,8,5],blinks:[0,2,3,4], score:[0,100,150,200], subIndex: 0, image: "blue", bunce: 150, speed:0.6)
```

Error I am getting is

> Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(level: Int, activeButtons: [UIButton], numberOfButtons: Int, timer: [Int], blinks: [Int], score: [Int], subIndex: Int, image: String, bunce: Int, speed: Double)' 
>   1. Expected an argument list of type '(Element)'

Comment: Make a struct.  Please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needed another braces around the element you are adding...

```
    var levels:[(
    level: Int,
    activeButtons: [UIButton],
    numberOfButtons: Int,
    timer: [Int],
    blinks: [Int],
    score: [Int],
    subIndex: Int,
    image: String,
    bunce : Int,
    speed: Double


    )] = []


    levels.append((level:1, activeButtons:[], numberOfButtons:2, timer:[0,10,8,5],blinks:[0,2,3,4], score:[0,100,150,200], subIndex: 0, image: "blue", bunce: 150, speed:0.6))
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue. why I needed that extra braces after upgrading to xcode 7?